# Mount SFTP server reachable via HTTP proxy as a windows local drive

Tags: windows, proxy, mount, sftp, windows-server

I need to mount SFTP server path as local drive in Windows Server with user credential. The problem is that the server is reachable only by HTTP proxy on port 80 without any authorization on proxy. How to configure that? Do I need some external software?

I did a research but withou any answers for http proxy server.

Comment: I don't think you  will find an answer for the proxy issue, unless you are incorrect about the nature of the proxy. an HTTP proxy is a type of Application Layer Gateway, so instead of proxying traffic the way SOCKS does, it proxies application command sequences  that are contained in that traffic. in HTTP, operations are invoked using strings like `connect superuser.com`, `get questions/1758416/...`, etc. the HTTP proxy knows HTTP, so it can do this. it doesn't know SFTP though.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look here:

https://winfsp.dev/rel/

But in real world scenario you should use Samba.